# Enable Lambda function to an S3 bucket using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

We are creating an S3 bucket using a CloudFormation template.  I would like to associate (Add an event to S3 bucket) a Lambda function whenever a file is added to the S3 bucket.

How is it possible through CloudFormation templates. What are the properties which needs to be used in CloudFormation.

Comment: You want a lambda triggered when a bucket is created or when an object (PutObject) created in the bucket?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Here's a complete, self-contained CloudFormation template that demonstrates how to trigger a Lambda function whenever a file is added to an S3 bucket:

[image: Launch Stack]

```yaml
Description: Upload an object to an S3 bucket, triggering a Lambda event, returning the object key as a Stack Output.
Parameters:
  Key:
    Description: S3 Object key
    Type: String
    Default: test
  Body:
    Description: S3 Object body content
    Type: String
    Default: TEST CONTENT
  BucketName:
    Description: S3 Bucket name
    Type: String
Resources:
  Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DependsOn: BucketPermission
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName
      NotificationConfiguration:
        LambdaConfigurations:
        - Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
          Function: !GetAtt BucketWatcher.Arn
  BucketPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: !Ref BucketWatcher
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceAccount: !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}"
  BucketWatcher:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: Sends a Wait Condition signal to Handle when invoked
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          exports.handler = function(event, context) {
            console.log("Request received:\n", JSON.stringify(event));
            var responseBody = JSON.stringify({
              "Status" : "SUCCESS",
              "UniqueId" : "Key",
              "Data" : event.Records[0].s3.object.key,
              "Reason" : ""
            });
            var https = require("https");
            var url = require("url");
            var parsedUrl = url.parse('${Handle}');
            var options = {
                hostname: parsedUrl.hostname,
                port: 443,
                path: parsedUrl.path,
                method: "PUT",
                headers: {
                    "content-type": "",
                    "content-length": responseBody.length
                }
            };
            var request = https.request(options, function(response) {
                console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);
                console.log("Status message: " + response.statusMessage);
                context.done();
            });
            request.on("error", function(error) {
                console.log("send(..) failed executing https.request(..): " + error);
                context.done();
            });
            request.write(responseBody);
            request.end();
          };
      Timeout: 30
      Runtime: nodejs4.3
  Handle:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle
  Wait:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition
    Properties:
      Handle: !Ref Handle
      Timeout: 300
  S3Object:
    Type: Custom::S3Object
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt S3ObjectFunction.Arn
      Bucket: !Ref Bucket
      Key: !Ref Key
      Body: !Ref Body
  S3ObjectFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: S3 Object Custom Resource
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          var response = require('cfn-response');
          var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
          var s3 = new AWS.S3();
          exports.handler = function(event, context) {
            console.log("Request received:\n", JSON.stringify(event));
            var responseData = {};
            if (event.RequestType == 'Create') {
              var params = {
                Bucket: event.ResourceProperties.Bucket,
                Key: event.ResourceProperties.Key,
                Body: event.ResourceProperties.Body
              };
              s3.putObject(params).promise().then(function(data) {
                response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, responseData);
              }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                response.send(event, context, response.FAILED, responseData);
              });
            } else if (event.RequestType == 'Delete') {
              var deleteParams = {
                Bucket: event.ResourceProperties.Bucket,
                Key: event.ResourceProperties.Key
              };
              s3.deleteObject(deleteParams).promise().then(function(data) {
                response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, responseData);
              }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                response.send(event, context, response.FAILED, responseData);
              });
            } else {
              response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, responseData);
            }
          };
      Timeout: 30
      Runtime: nodejs4.3
  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal: {Service: [lambda.amazonaws.com]}
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: S3Policy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 's3:PutObject'
                - 'S3:DeleteObject'
              Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}/${Key}"
Outputs:
  Result:
    Value: !GetAtt Wait.Data
```

Comment: Thank you very much for working example. It saved a lot of time! But could you please tell me why there is `S3Object` in that template? I do not see that it is refered anywhere?

Comment: @Cherry `S3Object` and `S3ObjectFunction` automatically creates an object in the S3 bucket to trigger the Lambda function, just for testing. Normally this would be triggered by objects you upload manually, so it's not needed in your own implementation.

Comment: @wjordan Is there a reason the S3Object needs the "ServiceToken"? Whenever I try to drop more files, the "BucketWatcher" gets invoked, but the "S3ObjectFunction" does not get invoked. Is this a permission/role issue? I am manually dropping text files into the "Bucket" that was created.

Comment: I realized, that the file actually needs to be named "test" for this to work properly. That is why my "S3ObjectFunction" was not being invoked

Comment: Apr 2021: This snippet doesn't create any functions when I run it. Does anyone know how to get it to work?

Comment: (using this inside a Python environment...should that matter?)

Comment: Update 2021: Update the nodeJS version from 4 to 14.x in order to build this stack.

Answer (score 10):

You need a `NotificationConfiguration` property in your CloudFormation template. Unfortunately, it seems to require the bucket to already exist.  To get around this, you can create an initial stack, then update it with the `NotificationConfiguration`. For example:

```js
    // template1.json
    {
      "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
      "Parameters": {
        "mylambda": {
          "Type": "String"
        }
      },
      "Resources": {
        "bucketperm": {
          "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
          "Properties" : {
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "FunctionName": {"Ref": "mylambda"},
            "Principal": "s3.amazonaws.com",
            "SourceAccount": {"Ref": "AWS::AccountId"},
            "SourceArn": { "Fn::Join": [":", [
                "arn", "aws", "s3", "" , "", {"Ref" : "mybucket"}]]
            }
          }
        },
        "mybucket": {
          "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket"
        }
      }
    }

    // template2.json -- adds the NotificationConfiguration
    {
      "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
      "Parameters": {
        "mylambda": {
          "Type": "String"
        }
      },
      "Resources": {
        "bucketperm": {
          "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
          "Properties" : {
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "FunctionName": {"Ref": "mylambda"},
            "Principal": "s3.amazonaws.com",
            "SourceAccount": {"Ref": "AWS::AccountId"},
            "SourceArn": { "Fn::Join": [":", [
                "arn", "aws", "s3", "" , "", {"Ref" : "mybucket"}]]
            }
          }
        },
        "mybucket": {
          "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
          "Properties": {
            "NotificationConfiguration": {
              "LambdaConfigurations": [
                {
                  "Event" : "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
                  "Function" : {"Ref": "mylambda"}
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

You can use the AWS CLI tool to create the stack like this:

```sh
    $ aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name mystack --template-body file://template1.json --parameters ParameterKey=mylambda,ParameterValue=<lambda arn>
    # wait until stack is created
    $ aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name mystack --template-body file://template2.json --parameters ParameterKey=mylambda,ParameterValue=<lambda arn>
```

Comment: Do we need write code for lambda here in resources section of CFT?? as you are referring to mylambda??

Comment: The question is how to trigger a lambda when a bucket is created not when a new file is added to the bucket.

Comment: The lambda doesn't have to be defined in the same template.  The bucket configuration just needs the lambda ARN.  If your lambda is set up somewhere else, just pass the ARN in as a template parameter.

Comment: @ataylor can you please mention in ur code how to pass ARN as template paramter..

Comment: I've updated my answer to take the lambda ARN as a parameter.

Comment: @ataylor it gives me error as "unable to validate configurations in the template" when i upload this template to create stack

Comment: Hmm, I get that error too.  To get around it, you need to create the bucket without the NotificationConfiguration, then update it with the NotificationConfiguration.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @ataylor im using lambda and nested stack to create an S3 bucket ,the nested stack also creates SNS,load balancer and application stacks...so now when i create S3 bucket w/o NotificationConfiguration after that do i need to use another Resource(using CFT) in nested stack to add NotificationConfiguration???

Comment: @ataylor i cannot updatestack in lambda function as im using create stack with nested stack...

Comment: @ataylor can you please look into this??

Comment: You should use capital I on the invokeFunction permission line:
lambda:InvokeFunction

At least - that fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that.

Comment: @ataylor I got  The following resource(s) failed to create: [mybucket]. . Rollback requested by user when executing the second command (with the second template)

Answer (score 2):

i have added below bucket perm along with notificationconfiguration in cloudformation which is used to create S3 bucket..it worked !!

```
"bucketperm": {
            "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
            "Properties": {
                "Action": "lambda:invokeFunction",
                "FunctionName": "<arnvalue>",
                "Principal": "s3.amazonaws.com"
            }
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. This is needed, but even the docs at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig.html#cfn-s3-bucket-notificationconfig-lambdaconfig mention this is a part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible through Cloudformation, and what you need to configure are:

1) `AWS::S3::Bucket` resource and,

2) `NotificationConfiguration` configuration (use `LambdaConfigurations` in this case) for the s3 resource above.

Related documentation that you need:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html#cfn-s3-bucket-notification

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig.html

Answer (score -2):

It is clearly stated in AWS docs that **AWS::S3::Bucket** is used to create a resource, If we have a bucket that exists already we can not modify it to add NotificationConfiguration.
So S3 bucket must not exist for above template to work. 
Let CloudFormation creates all resources including S3 bucket.

Comment: I updated an existing bucket with the NotificationConfiguration and the Lambda Permission and it worked.