# Create a Lambda notification in an S3 bucket with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create an S3 trigger for a Lambda function in a CloudFormation Template. The S3 bucket already exists, and the Lambda function is being created.

[This](https://serverfault.com/a/611069) says it's not possible to modify pre-existing infrastructure (S3 in this case) with a CFT, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36339880/5182113) seems to say that the bucket has to be pre-existing.

1. It seems that the trigger can't be created using a CFT type "AWS::Lambda..." and that the source service needs to create the trigger. In my case, that's a NotificationConfiguration-LambdaConfiguration for an s3 bucket. Is all of that correct?
2. When I try to add a NotificationConfiguration to an existing S3 bucket with a CFT, it says that I can't. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I am fairly certain that while the bucket has to exist, it does not have to exist before the creation of the template.  Would creating the bucket alongside the notification configuration and the lambda function in the same template fit your use case?  If so, this method will be much, much easier to help you with than modifying existing infrastructure.  Either way there is a solution, but one is much prettier

Comment: When you say 'S3 bucket already exists', are you also implying that the bucket was created outside of CloudFormation?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Unfortunately, the official `AWS::CloudFormation` template only allows you to control [`Amazon S3 NotificationConfiguration`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig.html) as a [`NotificationConfiguration` property](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html#cfn-s3-bucket-notification) of the parent `AWS::S3::Bucket` Resource, which means that you can't attach this configuration to any existing bucket, you have to apply it to a CloudFormation-managed bucket for it to work.

A workaround is to implement the [`PUT Bucket Notification` API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTnotification.html) call directly as a [Lambda-backed Custom Resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html) using the  [`putBucketNotificationConfiguration`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putBucketNotificationConfiguration-property) JavaScript API call. However, because modifying the NotificationConfiguration on S3 buckets is restricted to the bucket's creator, you also need to add an [`AWS::S3::BucketPolicy`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-policy.html) Resource granting your Lambda Function access to the `s3:PutBucketNotification` action.

Here's a complete, self-contained CloudFormation template that demonstrates how to trigger a Lambda function whenever a file is added to an *existing* S3 bucket, using 2 Lambda-Backed Custom Resources (`BucketConfiguration` to set the bucket notification configuration, `S3Object` to upload an object to the bucket) and a third Lambda function (`BucketWatcher` to trigger the Wait Condition when an object is uploaded to the bucket).

[image: Launch Stack]

```
Description: Upload an object to an S3 bucket, triggering a Lambda event, returning the object key as a Stack Output.
Parameters:
  Key:
    Description: S3 Object key
    Type: String
    Default: test
  Body:
    Description: S3 Object body content
    Type: String
    Default: TEST CONTENT
  BucketName:
    Description: S3 Bucket name (must already exist)
    Type: String
Resources:
  BucketConfiguration:
    Type: Custom::S3BucketConfiguration
    DependsOn:
    - BucketPermission
    - NotificationBucketPolicy
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt S3BucketConfiguration.Arn
      Bucket: !Ref BucketName
      NotificationConfiguration:
        LambdaFunctionConfigurations:
        - Events: ['s3:ObjectCreated:*']
          LambdaFunctionArn: !GetAtt BucketWatcher.Arn
  S3BucketConfiguration:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: S3 Object Custom Resource
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          var response = require('cfn-response');
          var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
          var s3 = new AWS.S3();
          exports.handler = function(event, context) {
            var respond = (e) => response.send(event, context, e ? response.FAILED : response.SUCCESS, e ? e : {});
            process.on('uncaughtException', e=>failed(e));
            var params = event.ResourceProperties;
            delete params.ServiceToken;
            if (event.RequestType === 'Delete') {
              params.NotificationConfiguration = {};
              s3.putBucketNotificationConfiguration(params).promise()
                .then((data)=>respond())
                .catch((e)=>respond());
            } else {
              s3.putBucketNotificationConfiguration(params).promise()
                .then((data)=>respond())
                .catch((e)=>respond(e));
            }
          };
      Timeout: 30
      Runtime: nodejs4.3
  BucketPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: !Ref BucketWatcher
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceAccount: !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}"
  BucketWatcher:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: Sends a Wait Condition signal to Handle when invoked
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          exports.handler = function(event, context) {
            console.log("Request received:\n", JSON.stringify(event));
            var responseBody = JSON.stringify({
              "Status" : "SUCCESS",
              "UniqueId" : "Key",
              "Data" : event.Records[0].s3.object.key,
              "Reason" : ""
            });
            var https = require("https");
            var url = require("url");
            var parsedUrl = url.parse('${Handle}');
            var options = {
                hostname: parsedUrl.hostname,
                port: 443,
                path: parsedUrl.path,
                method: "PUT",
                headers: {
                    "content-type": "",
                    "content-length": responseBody.length
                }
            };
            var request = https.request(options, function(response) {
                console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);
                console.log("Status message: " + response.statusMessage);
                context.done();
            });
            request.on("error", function(error) {
                console.log("send(..) failed executing https.request(..): " + error);
                context.done();
            });
            request.write(responseBody);
            request.end();
          };
      Timeout: 30
      Runtime: nodejs4.3
  Handle:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle
  Wait:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition
    Properties:
      Handle: !Ref Handle
      Timeout: 300
  S3Object:
    Type: Custom::S3Object
    DependsOn: BucketConfiguration
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt S3ObjectFunction.Arn
      Bucket: !Ref BucketName
      Key: !Ref Key
      Body: !Ref Body
  S3ObjectFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: S3 Object Custom Resource
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          var response = require('cfn-response');
          var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
          var s3 = new AWS.S3();
          exports.handler = function(event, context) {
            var respond = (e) => response.send(event, context, e ? response.FAILED : response.SUCCESS, e ? e : {});
            var params = event.ResourceProperties;
            delete params.ServiceToken;
            if (event.RequestType == 'Create' || event.RequestType == 'Update') {
              s3.putObject(params).promise()
                .then((data)=>respond())
                .catch((e)=>respond(e));
            } else if (event.RequestType == 'Delete') {
              delete params.Body;
              s3.deleteObject(params).promise()
                .then((data)=>respond())
                .catch((e)=>respond(e));
            } else {
              respond({Error: 'Invalid request type'});
            }
          };
      Timeout: 30
      Runtime: nodejs4.3
  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal: {Service: [lambda.amazonaws.com]}
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: S3Policy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 's3:PutObject'
                - 'S3:DeleteObject'
              Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}/${Key}"
  NotificationBucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref BucketName
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action:
            - 's3:PutBucketNotification'
            Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}"
            Principal:
              AWS: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
Outputs:
  Result:
    Value: !GetAtt Wait.Data
```

Comment: It's crazy how much code is necessary to setup simple things in AWS using CloudFormation

Comment: Similar solution using a CFN generic resource provider (boto3 proxy essentially): https://github.com/ab77/cfn-generic-custom-resource#s3

Answer (score 1):

I use another solution because personally I don't like custom resource. I create a cloud trail to capture S3 write events for the concerned bucket, then I create a cloudwatch/eventbridge rule with S3 event pattern to trigger my Lambda function. This way I can hook my Lambda function to an existing S3 bucket without touching it, and it can be easily done through cloudformation.

Comment: Note that this way doesn't work for cross-account senario because I found my cloud trail cannot catch s3 events on another account. This might be doable but I can't find an easy way to set it up.