# Programmatically add multiple event notifications to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I would like to use the below cloudformation template to create multiple event notifications on a single existing S3 bucket. However, even if I specify another "LambdaFunctionConfigurations" under the BucketConfiguration resource I only see one event created on the S3 bucket. I've also tried creating another BucketConfiguration resource with a separate event configured without any luck. I'm looking for any tips or advice that would help point me in the right direction. From what I gather the s3.putBucketNotification method will clear any existing event notification configuration. Please keep in mind that the CF template does create a single event notification (I'm looking to create multiple event notifications).

Model for below template:
[Create a Lambda notification in an S3 bucket with CloudFormation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752985/create-a-lambda-notification-in-an-s3-bucket-with-cloudformation)

```yaml
Description: >-
  Create an event notification for an existing S3 bucket
Parameters:
  BucketName:
    Description: S3 Bucket name (must already exist)
    Type: String
Resources:
  BucketConfiguration:
    Type: 'Custom::S3BucketConfiguration'
    DependsOn:
      - BucketPermission
      - NotificationBucketPolicy
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt S3BucketConfiguration.Arn
      Bucket: !Ref BucketName
      NotificationConfiguration:
        LambdaFunctionConfigurations:
          - Events:
              - 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
            LambdaFunctionArn: MyLambdaArn
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 606b322f-42fa-4d20-bae4-53374d7ad7ba
  S3BucketConfiguration:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Description: S3 Object Custom Resource
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          var response = require('cfn-response');
          var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
          var s3 = new AWS.S3();
          exports.handler = function(event, context) {
            var respond = (e) => response.send(event, context, e ? response.FAILED : response.SUCCESS, e ? e : {});
            process.on('uncaughtException', e=>failed(e));
            var params = event.ResourceProperties;
            delete params.ServiceToken;
            if (event.RequestType === 'Delete') {
              params.NotificationConfiguration = {};
              s3.putBucketNotificationConfiguration(params).promise()
                .then((data)=>respond())
                .catch((e)=>respond());
            } else {
              s3.putBucketNotificationConfiguration(params).promise()
                .then((data)=>respond())
                .catch((e)=>respond(e));
            }
          };
      Timeout: 30
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 1cefd553-f888-4b3b-8184-d96932a29227
  BucketPermission:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceAccount: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
      SourceArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}'
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 29f90f84-cfd0-43d2-8c2b-c173ec96c409
  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole'
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: S3Policy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 's3:PutObject'
                  - 'S3:DeleteObject'
                Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}'
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 3556f770-b7cd-4ac1-8afa-62a0319721b8
  NotificationBucketPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref BucketName
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 's3:PutBucketNotification'
            Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}'
            Principal:
              AWS: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 1f82086e-0d71-4731-8173-e3b8ee0da4dd
Metadata:
  'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
    3556f770-b7cd-4ac1-8afa-62a0319721b8:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 60
        'y': 90
      z: 1
      embeds: []
    1f82086e-0d71-4731-8173-e3b8ee0da4dd:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 180
        'y': 90
      z: 1
      embeds: []
    29f90f84-cfd0-43d2-8c2b-c173ec96c409:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 410
        'y': 90
      z: 1
      embeds: []
    1cefd553-f888-4b3b-8184-d96932a29227:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 300
        'y': 190
      z: 1
      embeds: []
    606b322f-42fa-4d20-bae4-53374d7ad7ba:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 300
        'y': 90
      z: 1
      embeds: []
      dependson:
        - 29f90f84-cfd0-43d2-8c2b-c173ec96c409
        - 1f82086e-0d71-4731-8173-e3b8ee0da4dd
```

Answer (score 6):

You are correct that it is not possible to have multiple Events defined for the same 'triggers'.

For example, in the S3 console I was successfully able to define:

- Multiple rules for the same **event** but a **different prefix**
- Multiple rules for the same **prefix** but a **different event**

However, I could **not** define multiple rules for the **same event** and **same prefix.** The error message was:

> Configuration is ambiguously defined. Cannot have overlapping suffixes in two rules if the prefixes are overlapping for the same event type.

Based on your question, it appears you want to trigger multiple Lambda functions for the same event within the same prefix (which includes 'the whole bucket'). For that, I would recommend:

- Create an **Amazon SNS topic**
- Create an **S3 Event** that points to the SNS topic
- **Subscribe** each Lambda function to the SNS topic

Comment: Is this still the case? I am trying to do something similar with terraform, and i have been unable to create multiple event from tf on the same s3 bucket with different prefixes to trigger different lambdas.

Comment: I suggest you try it manually in the Amazon S3 management console on another bucket just to test it out. I wonder if it is a limitation of Terraform?

Comment: I tried click building it and it looks like i can add another event. No idea why my terraform code does not want to append, and just keeps overriding the 1 event. I posted another question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63065323/multiple-lambda-triggered-based-on-multiple-s3-bucket-event-notifications?noredirect=1#comment111522725_63065323, would be great if you could take a look.