# Multiple lambda triggered based on multiple s3 bucket event notifications

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am new to the world of terraform and have been trying to essentially trigger multiple lambdas from different events configured on an s3 bucket. Every time I try to create it, it essentially overwrites the previous event and creates the last one as per the terraform plan. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. I saw a git issue which i could find clear resolution with.

Would appreciate any help with this!

Attached is the sample code i have written which is configurable at the environment level.

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/6934

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda-function" {
  s3_bucket     = "${var.project}-${var.env}-${var.artifacts-postfix}"
  s3_key        = "lambda/${var.project}-${var.env}-${var.lambda-name}/function.zip"
  function_name = "${var.project}-${var.env}-${var.lambda-name}"
  role          = var.lambda-role
  handler       = "handler.lambda_handler"
  timeout       = "60"

  runtime = "python3.7"

  environment {
    variables = var.env-variables
  }

  tags = {
    Name    = "${var.project}-${var.env}-${var.lambda-name}"
    Project = var.project
    Env     = var.env
  }
}


resource "aws_lambda_permission" "s3-trigger" {
  count         = var.activate-trigger ? 1 : 0 
  statement_id  = "${var.project}-${var.env}-${var.lambda-name}-statement-id"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = "${var.project}-${var.env}-${var.lambda-name}"
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket-name}"
  depends_on    = [aws_lambda_function.lambda-function]
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  count  = var.activate-trigger ? 1 : 0 
  bucket = var.bucket-name

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = aws_lambda_function.lambda-function.arn
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_prefix       = var.s3-key-prefix
    filter_suffix       = var.s3-key-suffix
    id                  = "${var.project}-${var.env}-${var.lambda-name}-event-id"
  }

  depends_on = [aws_lambda_permission.s3-trigger]
}
```

Comment: Your code shows only one bucket_notification event for `s3:ObjectCreated`. Where are those other ones?

Comment: I want to create a trigger on a single bucket, although my prefixes are different which would trigger different lambda functions.

Comment: Based on the github link you provided and the docs, its not supported. You would have to explicitly add all events at once in  a single `aws_s3_bucket_notification` resource.

Comment: Got it! Becoming difficult to deal with this really.

Comment: aws_s3_bucket_notification creates the entire bucket config, which includes multiple notification entries lambda_function {) blocks. all the lambda blocks and you should be fine.

Comment: can you please show me through some sample code? I am not really sure what you mean!

Answer (score 0):

A year after, and I hit the same wall. ID is not a unique identifier that will create multiple notifications, is an optional value. AWS assigns the real unique identifier.

In my scenario, I got emails coming through SES and stored in S3, so I ending publishing through SNS when I got the email stored in s3 using SES actions. Got lambda subscribed to SNS and doing the work once it gets the message.

Switched from aws_s3_bucket_notification to aws_sns_topic_subscription