# Cloudformation - Lambda Trigger on S3 Event? (Bucket Already Exists)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to add a trigger to a Lambda function in Cloudformation for s3 events, where the s3 bucket already exists? (i.e, is not created by said template)

I have tried to find an example of this online, but it appears that the only way to set this trigger in CF is by using the bucket notification configuration.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752985/create-a-lambda-notification-in-an-s3-bucket-with-cloudformation

Answer (score 2):

Cloudformation cannot do this directly. However, Cloudformation Custom Resources can call Lambda functions, and Lambda functions can do whatever you program them to do. You could write a Lambda function which creates or deletes some resource based on whatever logic you want.

See more:
[AWS Lambda-backed Custom Resources - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html)