# Can't create a Lambda and Bucket using serverless.yml

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I'm trying to create a basic lambda and an S3 bucket using the Serverless Framework. I have cut out a small code snippet from this post: [Enable Lambda function to an S3 bucket using cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338890/enable-lambda-function-to-an-s3-bucket-using-cloudformation)

```
# serverless.yml

service: MyTest
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7
resources:
  Resources:
    Bucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: MyBucket12345
    MyFunc:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
      Properties:
        Handler: handler.MyFunc


# handler.py

def MyFunc(event, context):
    print(event)
```

Output:

```
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Creating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack create progress...
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - MyTest-dev
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::S3::Bucket - ServerlessDeploymentBucket
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::S3::Bucket - ServerlessDeploymentBucket
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::S3::Bucket - ServerlessDeploymentBucket
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::S3::BucketPolicy - ServerlessDeploymentBucketPolicy
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::S3::BucketPolicy - ServerlessDeploymentBucketPolicy
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::S3::BucketPolicy - ServerlessDeploymentBucketPolicy
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - MyTest-dev
Serverless: Stack create finished...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...

  Type Error ---------------------------------------------

  TypeError: Cannot set property 'S3Key' of undefined
```

Comment: Looking at it again, I made mistake in my answer. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Np. I've pasted an updated code snippet with new error

Comment: Your link is to CloudFormation (CFN) template, not serverless template. serverless is related to CFN, but has different structure. You have to look up how to properly use serverless framework. My mistake was that I also confused them :-(

Comment: If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it

Comment: Thanks, I provided new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338890/enable-lambda-function-to-an-s3-bucket-using-cloudformation) provided in the question showcases a [CloudFormation (CFN) template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html), not [serverless framework template](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/intro/). Although there are similarities between the two, they are **different**.

The code in the question is a mixture of both CFN and serverless templates, which makes it not work in both systems.

Thus to solve the issue, you have to check and find [examples](https://www.serverless.com/examples/) for serverless framework templates, not CFN. Then you modify your current template into valid serverless template.

Comment: Note also that AWS Serverless Application Model (SAM) isn't quite the same as Serverless; SAM includes many of the functionality of CFN templates, while Serverless does not (otherwise very similar). One necessary difference is that SAM can only run on AWS, while Serverless is more platform agnostic.